# How to bind the "tapped" Eventhandler from a ListView used in a ContentView context?

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my Xamarin project. I would like to create a control that is using a ListView thanks to a "ContentView". I'm using the ContentView approach because I should reuse this controls element several times in my project in a modular way. 
I can succesfuly creates the binding properties for the different elements of my View. 
But I cannot find the way to create the Binding properties for the actions realted to my Listview ("Tapped" for instance). I already made this in other ContentView by using the "Command" proppeties of element and EventHandlers (for exemple Button.Command). But sounds like ListView does not implement this propeties.

Here it is the code I'm using so far for my ListView

```
    public partial class ItemSelectListView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemListViewProperty=
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemListView", typeof(IEnumerable<Item>), typeof(ItemSelectListView), default(Item));

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemListView
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Item>)GetValue(ItemListViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemListViewProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleLabelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("TitleLabel", typeof(string), typeof(ItemSelectListView), default(string));

    public string TitleLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public ItemSelectListView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        ListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ItemListView", source: this));
        Title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("TitleLabel", source: this));            

    }
}
```

And here it is for example the way I'm used to create the EventHandler that I cannot replicate for the ListView

```
    public partial class ItemSelectButtonView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LeftButtonTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("LeftButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(ItemSelectButtonView), default(string));

    public string LeftButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LeftButtonTextProperty);}
        set { SetValue(LeftButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RightButtonTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("RightButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(ItemSelectButtonView), default(string));

    public string RightButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RightButtonTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public event EventHandler RightButtonClicked;
    public event EventHandler LeftButtonClicked;



    public ItemSelectButtonView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        LeftButton.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("LeftButtonText", source: this));
        RightButton.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("RightButtonText", source: this));

        LeftButton.Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            LeftButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });

        RightButton.Command = new Command(() =>
        {
            RightButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });
    }

}
```

So how I could get the same result with a ListView?

Thanks,

Comment: Not understand why should custom a contentview like ListView.You can show more logic you designed and why should need this. **ListView** also self has `ItemSelected` property.If you want custom ViewCell, you can use `ListView.ItemTemplate` to do .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells

Answer (score 0):

I could finally do the following way. 
Not sure if it is the cleanest one.

```
public partial class ItemSelectListView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemListViewProperty=
        BindableProperty.Create("ItemListView", typeof(IEnumerable<Item>), typeof(ItemSelectListView), default(Item));

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemListView
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<Item>)GetValue(ItemListViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemListViewProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleLabelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("TitleLabel", typeof(string), typeof(ItemSelectListView), default(string));

    public string TitleLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> ItemSelected;

    public void NotifyItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        ItemSelected(sender, e);
    }

        public ItemSelectListView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        ItemsListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ItemListView", source: this));
        Title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("TitleLabel", source: this));
        ItemsListView.ItemSelected += NotifyItemSelected;
        ItemsListView.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("ItemSelected", source: this));
    }
}
```